# SharePoint List Order - drag and drop?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, microsoft-lists

Is there an easy way to order list items in SharePoint Online? I just would like to, for example, swap two rows.

Is there an easy way to do this/drag and drop maybe?

Is ordering strictly done by insertion order or by sorting? Do I have to create a custom Column to use for sorting/ordering purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no OOTB drag/drop functionality available in SharePoint lists to swap two items/rows.

Either you can sort on existing columns or you have to create a new column for applying sorting based on it:

[image]

---

There was one feature posted on Microsoft 365 roadmap site related to this but I am not sure if it is released to all SharePoint online tenants.

[image]

**Source**: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=82070

---

**Similar threads**:

1. [SharePoint re-order item order in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571285/sharepoint-re-order-item-order-in-the-list)
2. [Lists app in Teams - reordering items (rows)](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/lists-app-in-teams-reordering-items-rows/4c949d02-13f7-4bbe-a49c-9035475787dd)
3. [Drag and Drop SharePoint List by row for change items order](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37955/drag-and-drop-sharepoint-list-by-row-for-change-items-order) - This may not be helpful for you as it is for classic experience

Answer (score 1):

The ID column is an internal identity-like column. You cannot change the value. If you need a column that you can order by (and change), just create a new column called SortOrder or something. Then sort by that column.

---

**If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.**